# PHP: PDO - Selecting multiple rows from a table

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I have a php script, which looks up a translation for a given word:

```
$word = "the";
$db = new PDO("sqlite:words.sqlite");
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT word, translation FROM words where word = ?");
$sth->execute(array($word]));
```

However, I wish to replace the string variable $word with an array called $words and look up the translations for a set of words. Can I execute a single statement to retrieve all of these values? How is this implemented in terms of code?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mysql function IN in conjuction with your array. See this previous stack post: [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)